# Cannot truly separate parts

Tags: edit-mode

There must be an easy answer to this. I'm in 2.82 and I made 10 dupliverts of a mesh on a plane with 12 points. I made them all real in object mode, selected all in edit mode, did P - separate by loose parts. I thought all was well as I could move each mesh independently and they each had their own origin. No trouble moving them independently etc. However when I go into edit mode for any of the 'independent' meshes, all the other ex-dupliverts are selected too! I cannot make them individual mesh-wise, even though they appear to be independent objects and are listed as such. I cannot even colour them independently. Any ideas?

Edit: here is the file.
[image]

Comment: Did you duplicate them with SHIFT-d or with ALT-d? In the second case they are the same mesh in different objects. Could you provide the file?

Comment: Hi mugnozzo, I did neither. I just parented the mesh to the plane and in the instancing tab changed from None to Verts or Faces. How do I provide the file?

Comment: You can from here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=QQ4OSMW4" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QQ4OSMW4/)

Comment: Ok! I gave an answer below and I edited your Question linking the file directly there, so all will be clearer to those who will see the question in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The objects in the file you provided in the comments of your question are linked copies.

1. Select them all together;
2. press F3 (or spacebar, if in blender 2,79 or earlier);
3. type "make single user" to find the "Make Single User" command and click it;
4. in the popup that appears check "Object Data" (see img) and press OK.

[image]

Comment: Aha...many thanks, you are my hero. I had just assumed that the separation by loose parts did all that, obviously not. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: @mugnozzo Also available in Object mode under _Header menu > Object > Relations_

Comment: Right! I have the habit of using the search menu and I often don't remember where the commands are. :-) Thanks!